# FFTW : how to prevent breaking aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, fftw, strict-aliasing

I have a code which uses the `std::complex<double>` type.
From [FFTW Manual](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html) :

> if you have a variable `complex<double> *x`, you can pass it directly to FFTW via `reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(x)`.

However, when I do this in my code :

```
tmp_spectrum = reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(fftw_alloc_complex(conf.spectrumSize()));
plan_bw_temp = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(conf.FFTSize(), reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(tmp_spectrum), tmp_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I get `dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`.
How to solve this warning ? Thanks !

Comment: Encapsulate in a function where you disable the warning?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here:

- Just create a `fftw_complex` when you need one: `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(conf.FFTSize(), fftw_complex(tmp_spectrum.real(), tmp_spectrum.imag()), tmp_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`
- Don't use the C++ language's complex type in your code, and only use the `fftw_complex` type.
- Disable ALL strict-alias optimizations and enforcement in the appropriate translation unit with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Silencing just the warning is *not* safe as it might result in broken code.

Comment: For 1., not sure it could work because here I have an array of complex values, not a single one.
For 2., I can't because I might bind other FFT libraries instead of fftw. So I need a generic type.
So it leaves me with the optimization-disabling method... How to disable it only for one file ?