# Avoiding aliasing/type punning with fftw

Tags: c++, fftw, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I guess I have an aliasing problem. 
I am using the fftw-library, which supports in-place FFTs. This means, that I call a fftw-function which has an interface similar to this:

```
void fftwFunction(double* input, fftw_complex* output);
```

where `fftw_complex` is `double[2]`. "In-place" means that the `input` and `output` arrays can point to the same physical array. (Note: Gives better performance.)

Now, I am using it like this:

```
class fftwClass
{
public:
  void AllocateMemory(size_t numBytes)
  {
    void* allocatedMemory = fftw_malloc(numBytes); // Aligned malloc
    mRealValues = reinterpret_cast<double*>(allocatedMemory);
    mFourierValues = reinterpret_cast< std::complex<double>* >(allocatedMemory);
  }

  void DoForwardFFT()
  {
    // Transformation from the real to the fourier-space.
    fftwFunction(mRealValues, mFourierValues);
  }

  void DoSomethingReal()
  {
    // Read and modify mRealValues
    // E.g.:
    mRealValues[0] = 5;
  }

  void DoSomethingFourier()
  {
    // Read and modify mFourierValues
    // E.g.:
    mFourierValues[0] = 5;
  }

private:
  double* mRealValues;
  std::complex<double>* mFourierValues;
};
```

The call sequence can be like this: `AllocateMemory()`, `DoSomethingReal()`, `DoForwardFFT()`, `DoSomethingFourier()`.

My questions:

- `mRealValues` and `mFourierValues` point to the same array, but have different types. Therefore I have an aliasing/type-punning problem in `DoSomethingReal()` and `DoSomethingFourier()`, haven't I?
- Although gcc (`-Wall -Wextra`) nor Intel's nor Microsoft's compiler have warned me so far about any aliasing problem, and the program runs fine: Could there be a silent problem due to the aliasing?
- What are possible solutions to solve this?

For gcc, the following compiles without warning, but does this solve the problem?

```
__attribute__((__may_alias__)) double* mRealValues;
__attribute__((__may_alias__)) std::complex<double>* mFourierValues;
```

Note regarding the cast to `std::complex`: [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/~fftw/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html#Complex-numbers) recommends it, and as far as I know this is defined behaviour in C++11. In any case, I have a `static_assert` in place to check that the sizes match, and this is not my question.
In any case, the actual code looks different, as fftw's usage is more complex (and of course I clean-up the allocated memory).

Also note, I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408673/fftw-how-to-prevent-breaking-aliasing-rules) post, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: *"In any case, I have a `static_assert` in place to check that the sizes match"* Not necessary. [complex.numbers]/4 guarantees that `complex<T>` has the size `2*sizeof(T)` (indirectly via requirements on pointer arithmetics). It also allows aliasing (debatable on a language-lawyer level) an object of type `complex<T>` with an lvalue of type `T(&)[2]` plus pointer arithmetics.